# How do I find the return values of AVR code?

Tags: arduino, avr

I am trying to find the 2 byte return value of this code:

```
ldi r18, 16
lsl r18
mov r24, r18
mov r25, r1
ret
```

I thought the answer would be 0x0020 but that is incorrect. I also tried 0x0030 and that is not right either.

Comment: What do you mean by the "return value"? This code manipulates a value in register `r18` and ultimately loads the value `0x20` into register `r24`, and then loads an unknown value from `r1` into `r25`.

Comment: Read the assembly language reference to see what `ret` does.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, question about "return values" in assembler has no sense, because there is no some predefined place where return values are to be stored.

Unless there is some convention how and where return values should be stored, they may be stored anyhow and anywhere, also initial values of registers are unknown.

But, probably you are talking about some particular convention. For example, [calling convention, used in AVR-GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc)

In this case the whole code obtains some sense. For example, it said that the 16-bit return value is stored in the register pair `r25:r24`, and register `r1` assumed to contain zero.

In this case:

```
ldi r18, 16  -- load decimal value 16 into r18
lsl r18      -- shift left value in r18: now r18 contains 32
mov r24, r18 -- copy 32 from r18 into r24
mov r25, r1  -- copy value of r1, which assumed to contain 0, into r25
ret  -- return from subroutine, now r25:r24 contains value 32, or 0x0020
```